# How to prevent user to change the timer value from front-end?

Tags: javascript, timer

I am designing a online exam website where i need to have a timer display. i want to prevent user to go to inspect page and reset timer value. How can i do that? I also want timer should not refresh even after user refresh the page. I cannot send time value from backend as I am using AWS lambda and each invocation has a cost. 
please suggest some solution for the same.

Comment: You can't keep a user from changing client side.

Comment: Then can u suggest a way i can implement that?

Comment: Server side.  But you said you don't want a server side solution.